# Change the path of the offline plotly plot

Tags: python, plotly

I'm working with plotly and python API offline.

If I create a simple plot, e.g.

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Box

plot([Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 6])])
```

the plot is saved by default in my `/home/user` folder, I'm on a Debian machine).

How can I change this behavior and choose another folder ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

*mvelay* method works fine!

But way if the same plot is made with the following method?

```
plotly.offline.plot({
        "data": [
        Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 6])
        ],
        "layout": Layout(
        showlegend=True
        )
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use plotly offline API as follows:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Box

plot([Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 6])], filename='/your/file/path')
```

Comment: awesome! Where did you get this information? I've looked into the python API but I did not find this additional parameter.

Comment: I have tried it :) You are right this is not in the official doc but same behaviour that online API

Comment: ah ok thanks ;) should try more when I'm facing other troubles! Thanks again

Comment: hey.. I have another question.. What if I edit the script (see edits)? In that way your method does not work anymore..